# Apache has many PHP session files

Tags: apache-2.2, php, sles, session

```
# ls /var/lib/php5 | wc -l
7488

# ls -la
-rw-------  1 wwwrun www       0 Nov  9 15:30 sess_vtuh671rlafdidfjmgjfu6065p4tfieg
-rw-------  1 wwwrun www       0 Nov 12 02:30 sess_vu9pn476oiqbsd20q4s2brt60b9vg90d
-rw-------  1 wwwrun www       0 Nov  9 15:07 sess_vuonfs2cqsdiq8ja51ornh6lp5j9mf93
-rw-------  1 wwwrun www       0 Nov  9 16:02 sess_vuutcad8as55il34db3uqhqrsltd4q6o
-rw-------  1 wwwrun www       0 Nov  9 23:26 sess_vv2mrv5dnlnts6das4g5jlfldael4l0e
-rw-------  1 wwwrun www      44 Nov  9 20:35 sess_vvc0cfjuvk3lqb5m97fv6gsmv6bjhsdk
-rw-------  1 wwwrun www       0 Nov  9 10:33 sess_vvq82fhj9lg29gaejemlb2lrk25mqv7d
-rw-------  1 wwwrun www       0 Nov  9 20:36 sess_vvtd4ka8rfmcroa34unl06916ubj8sb9
```

Most of them are empty. There are not so many users on the server so I wonder where those files came from.

Is this a problem or how does apache handle those file? Do they get delete automaticly?

Could this be caused by a bad PHP file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is from the deault session handler (you didn't say).

Yes, the files should get remove automatically, depending on the settings of [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) and [session.gc_probability](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability). If you've currently got the default settings, then increasing the latter will reduce the number of files.

But unless you have performance / capacity issues it's nothing to worry about.

That you have so many empty files implies that your server is spending a significant amount of time managing no data - if you have performance problems then smarter handling of empty sessions may help. i.e. re-engineer your code - but do read the manual on how session handling works first.